# Seinfeld - The Wizard - What's the name of the rap song played as Elaine enters her boyfriend's apartment?

Tags: identify-this-song, soundtrack, rap

In the Seinfeld episode `The Wizard` as Elaine visits her new boyfriend in his apartment for the first time there is a rap song playing while Elaine stands in the hallway and eventually enters. She thinks the music is coming from her boyfriend's apartment but it's actually coming from a neighbour.

What's the name and artist of this song?

https://youtu.be/wM0vz2Z8lRw?t=57

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure this is Kick Da Flow by M-Project. The [lyrics](https://www.lololyrics.com/lyrics/8210.html) match up well with what I could make out.

I however can't find a video for it nor can find it on my music streaming service, so I can't verify.

Answer (score 1):

I just spoke with Johnathan Wolff who wrote it. [image]